# What is the difference between signing plugin and signingConfigs in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

As the title says.

I want to sign an Android archive (AAR) which is going to be distributed to 3rd parties, but can't get it done with `signingConfigs`:

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias "myandroidkey"
            keyPassword "myPassword"
            storeFile file("/Users/carsten/Keystores/android.jks")
            storePassword "myPassword"
        }
    }
```

I had a look at the `signing` plugin, but wondering why are there 2 features for the same thing in Gradle and what their differences are?

Comment: You seem to be mixing standard Gradle features with Android specific things, therefore simply  confusing yourself. What's the actual problem?

Comment: I'm trying to sign an AAR with the config above in `build.gradle`. AAR file is created without error messages, but it isn't signed. I couldn't find any information about how to do that or whether it's possible at all. Instead, I found some articles about how to use the `signing` plugin and have been confused since than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got is solved by signing the AAR without Gradle as described at https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Respectively added this section to the Ant script:

```
<target name="sign" description="Sign the AAR" depends="">
    <signjar keystore="${basedir}/${key.store}"
        storepass="${key.store.password}"
        sigalg="SHA1withRSA"
        digestalg="SHA1"
        alias="${key.alias}"
        keypass="${key.alias.password}"
        jar="${basedir}/../../build/outputs/aar/myLib-release.aar">
    </signjar>
</target>
```